# How to prevent RecyclerView adding empty space in rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have CheckBox and when is it clicked ,my text view should be placed on the left side of RecyclerView aka first row, and if it left unchecked it should be placed on the right side of RecyclerView aka second row. I tried with GridLayoutManager but nothing happened. Basically I am trying to get something like this:[image]

and this is what I got:
[image]
I got empty space on left side and number 25 is not on top, basically getting space on the right side also

my code:`

```
if (modelClass.isContingent()) {
                binding.benefiiaryContigentTV.setText(modelClass.getPercentage());
               // binding.benefiiaryPercentageTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {

                binding.benefiiaryPercentageTV.setText(modelClass.getPercentage());
            }
```

my LIneaarLayoutManager:

```
  // Create layout manager with initial prefetch item count
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                binding.rvNonregisteredList.getContext(),
                LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                true
        );
        layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(modelClass.getNonRegBeneficiarisList().size());
        // Create sub item view adapter
        NonRegBeneficiarisAdapter subItemAdapter = new NonRegBeneficiarisAdapter(modelClass.getNonRegBeneficiarisList(), context);

        binding.rvNonregisteredList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.rvNonregisteredList.setAdapter(subItemAdapter);
        binding.rvNonregisteredList.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
```

`
and my fragment:

```
private void buildSubItemList(List<NonRegBeneficiaris> subItemList) {
        NonRegBeneficiaris subItem = new NonRegBeneficiaris();
        subItemList.add(subItem);
}
```

and here i am calling this method:

```
for (int i = 0; i<assetsModel.getNonRegisteredModelList().size()-1;i++){
                buildSubItemList(assetsModel.getNonRegisteredModelList().get(i).getNonRegBeneficiarisList());
            }
```

my xml:

```
`<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bela">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/benefiiary_percentage_TV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#8fa2b0"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_view3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vertical_view3"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:background="@color/background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/benefiiary_contigent_TV"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/benefiiary_percentage_TV"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/benefiiary_contigent_TV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#8fa2b0"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vertical_view3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: can you share your cardview xml?

Comment: i am using constraint layout,but shure i will put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an idea:

use a cardview layout like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelRight"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

inflate it in your RecyclerView adapter onCreateViewHolder method and whenever a checkBox is unchecked, you can remove the clicked checkbox view from panelLeft and add it to panelRight and vice versa.

final result before and after clicking some of the CheckBoxes:

before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: by CardView layout i mean the layout XML file that you inflate in your RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show items as wanted , you better use two **RecylcerView** , because while using one the view will always be considered as a row , so you will never avoid space since you are just changing the gravity .

So then anytime you check the box your remove/add item to the list and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your two `adapter`

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: This, i believe, will cause a few problems. first, the two RecyclerViews will be independent of each other which i don't think is what he wants.Also handling ItemView click listeners can cause confusion since there are two separate RecyclerViews. i believe he wants to be able to move checkbox views from left to right and vice versa on any given RecyclerView item. in the solution I gave above, when you remove views from panelLeft to panelRight ,you should not get any spaces since they are Linear layouts and they stack views on top of each other.